# is it possible to close current tab of browser using java/spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

my requirement is to close the current tab using java/Spring boot . is there any way to do this with java.
if not . then can we use other language in java to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Window. close() method closes the current window, or the window on which it was called. This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window. open() method.

Since Java is a back-end language, it cannot be used to close current windows.

Instead, use:

```
close();
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
window.close();
```

(It assumes the current tab)